# Sending form data with angular 12 file upload but form file null (.net core)

Tags: c#, .net, angular, .net-core, angular12

I want to upload files with my data on Angular side. But when we check the data added to the form on the angular side, there is no problem, the file is null on the service side. Dto and angular variable names etc are the same. Please help me.

[backendService](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2p0G.png)

**Backend**

**Dto**

```
public class SampleAnalysisFileDto
{
 
   IFormFile File { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
     [HttpPost("{id}")]
        [GrandAuthorize(GrandPermission.EndpointPermission, Grands.SampleAnalysisUpdate + "," + Grands.SampleAnalysesByPerosonnel, GrandFilterType.Or)]
        public async Task<ServiceResponse<bool>> SampleAnalysisUpdate(int id, [FromForm] SampleAnalysisFileDto model)
        {
            return await AspectProxy<IOrderService>.Create(_orderService).SampleAnalysisUpdate(id, model);
        }
```

**Frontend**

**baseService**

```
update(apiControllerName: string, metot: string, entity: any) {
    return this.http.put<any>(environment.apiUrl + '/' + apiControllerName + '/' + metot + '/' + 1, entity, { headers: this.jwt_header() });
  }
```

**SampleAnalysis ts**

```
     onFile(id: number) {
        this._genelServis.onFile(id);
      }
    
     
    
         onSubmit() {
    
        const formData: FormData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', this.file_);
        formData.append('name','deneme');
          
        this._genelServis.lodingShow();
        this._baseServis.update("Order", "SampleAnalysisUpdate", formData).subscribe(
          (data: any) => {
            this._genelServis.lodinghide();
            if (Helpers.ExcuteData(data, false) === true) {
              this.onSubmitSaveAfter.emit(this.entity.id);
              
              this.modalClose();
            }
          },
          error => {
            this._genelServis.lodinghide();
          });
      }
```

**Frontend html**

```
 <div class="modal-header">
      <h4 class="modal-title"><app-language-com [labelCode]="'UI_ANALIZI_RAPOR'"></app-language-com></h4>
      <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="activeModal.close('Close click')">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
    </div>
    
    <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutWrap="wrap">
      <!-- column -->
      <div fxFlex.gt-sm="100" fxFlex.gt-xs="100" fxFlex="100">
        <mat-card>
          <mat-card-content>
            <!-- Row -->
    
            <form class="basic-form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" autocomplete="off" enctype="multipart/form-data">
              <div fxLayout="row wrap" class="vys-form-element">
                <!-- column -->
                <div fxFlex.gt-md="100" fxFlex="100" class="vys-form-element" style="margin-top: 10px;">
                  <mat-form-field>
                    <mat-label>* <app-language-com [labelCode]="'UI_RAPOR_ACIKLAMA'"></app-language-com></mat-label>
                    <textarea matInput type="text" value="" name="input1reportContent" [(ngModel)]="entity.reportContent" style="height: 105px;" maxlength="2000"></textarea>
                  </mat-form-field>
                  <app-knumber-com [entity]="entity?.statusContent" [knumber]="2000"></app-knumber-com>
                </div>
                <div fxFlex.gt-sm="100" fxFlex="100" class="vys-form-element">
                  <input type="file" id="files" style="display: contents;" (change)="onfileSelected($event)" />
    
                  <a href="javascript:;" title="Rapor Seç">
                    <mat-icon _ngcontent-feo-c354="" role="img" for="files" class="mat-icon notranslate material-icons mat-icon-no-color" aria-hidden="true" data-mat-icon-type="font">file_download</mat-icon>
                    <label for="files">Rapor Seç</label>
                  </a>
                  &nbsp;&nbsp;<label>{{fileName}}</label>&nbsp;
                  <a href="javascript:;" title="Dosyayı Sil" (click)="entity.reportFileId = 0;fileName = '';" *ngIf="entity.reportFileId > 0">
                    <mat-icon _ngcontent-feo-c354="" role="img" for="files" class="mat-icon notranslate material-icons mat-icon-no-color" aria-hidden="true" data-mat-icon-type="font">delete</mat-icon>
                    &nbsp;<label>Dosyayı Sil</label>
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div fxFlex.gt-sm="70" fxFlex="70" style="text-align: right;margin-top:10px">
                  <button mat-raised-button color="primary" type="submit"><app-language-com [labelCode]="'UI_KAYDET'"></app-language-com></button>    &nbsp;&nbsp;
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-light" id="modalUsercloseId" (click)="activeModal.close('Close click')"><app-language-com [labelCode]="'UI_KAPAT'"></app-language-com></button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </mat-card-content>
        </mat-card>
      </div>
      <!-- column -->
    </div>
```

Comment: Provide `public` access modifier to the `File` property.

Comment: You're right, the error has been resolved.